# How to duplicate the uploaded GIF and change its size?

Tags: php

Can anyone suggest a solution to the issue?
There is such a code

```
private function saveGif() {
    $path = PATH_TEMP . '/' . $this->post('hash') . '.gif';
    $this->web->Request($this->post('external'), null, true)->SaveToFile($path);
}

private function saveThumbs() {
    $path = PATH_TEMP . '/' . $this->post('hash');
    $img = new Image($path . '.gif');
    $img->toFile($path . '.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
    $img->resize(350, null)->toFile(PATH_TEMP . '/m_' . $this->post('hash') .'.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
}
```

If you add

```
$img->resize(250, null)->toFile(PATH_TEMP . '/m_' . $this->post('hash') .'.gif', 'image/gif');
```

Then a file m_...gif of the desired size is created, but there is no animation in the gif.
Maybe of course I'm not looking there, but still.

Sorry if I'm not writing correctly.

It is necessary that when uploading a gif to the site, the file appears m_...gif, with the width I need.

Comment: What image library is it? Maybe it is not capable of handling animated GIF.

Comment: Website https://gifki.su, It seems to me laravel

Comment: That's what the library is - PHPResizeGif - https://github.com/Grandt/PHPResizeGif

Comment: Buut then the call syntax is different like `ResizeGif::ResizeToWidth($srcFile, $dstFile, 100);`.